# Usage clarification of nouns format and formatting

Tags: word-choice, differences

How do the following two sentences differ in meaning?

> 1. Ensure the **formatting** of the text
> 2. Ensure the **format** of the text

Comment: The second is unnatural. 'Formatting' is clearly understood as typesetting etc. The second? No idea what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ensure the formatting of the text

This indicates that the speaker wants the listener to make sure that he formats the text. But it doesn't say or imply anything more about *how* it must be done. Also, *formatting* is the present participle form of *format*.

> Ensure the format of the text *(to be like something)*

Rephrase it as:

> Ensure the text's format

The implication becomes more clear. There must be some standard of rule for formatting that text and if you were to complete that sentence with *like this* or *as how we discussed in the meeting* it answers the question *how should I format this text*?

Comment: Thank you very much, it explains a lot... It's crystal clear for me now

Answer (score 0):

According to 'www.wordwebonline.com' both terms  can be used as  nouns and have the same meaning:

[Format](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=Format)/[Formatting](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=Formatting):

> - Noun: format  'for,mat
>     The organization of information according to preset specifications (usually for computer processing)
> - formatting, data format, data formatting.

In your sentences *format and formatting* are used as nouns so the meaning is the same. Actually  the first sentence may hint at  *the process of formatting* so it probably needs more specification to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: context here is manager asking subordinate following,

In the meantime, can you get the team to have a look at the site and ensure the formatting of the text and templates are correct.